# Requesting css style as text/css get response as text/html?

Tags: html, css, firefox

Basically I have:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
```

by doing this I get a console error saying: `main.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.`

through sniffing my browser network tab, It appears that the request is made as `text/css` but the response comes as `text/html`.

Request Headers (0.361 KB):

```
User-Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; linux x86_64; rv:52.0) gecko/20100101"
Accept: "text/css,*/*;q=0.1"
Accept-language: "en-US, e;q=0.5"
Accept-Encoding: "gzip, deflate"
```

Response Header (0.123 KB):

```
Content-Type: "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"
Date:"FRI 20 Oct 2017 ..."
Transfer-Encoding: "chunked"
```

FYI: This stylesheet is request in mutiple pages, at the other pages it works but not here.

Much regards

Comment: "through sniffing my browser network tab, It appears that the request is made as text/css but the response comes as text/html." — That is what the error message said. You need to find out *why* (which will involve looking at the URL for the CSS file that you are requesting and examining how the server handles it).

Comment: @Quentin Ahh sry for my late reply! anyway, I am using apache 9 configured with eclipse. And also the same stylesheet is being request by multiple pages but the error pop only on just one page dont really know why. you said "Looking at the URL for the CSS file and examine it" well i dont know how to do that. apache responds with the contents requested automatically soo...